# Python Check dictionary object for correct keys throw custom exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

So I have a method that takes a dictionary object as a parameter. I want to check over the dictionary to make sure it has all the correct keys and if not throw a custom exception. The code I have so far works but I am thinking there might be a better way. (Using Python 2.7)

```
def my_method(temp_dict):
    #this is the part that looks messy and I would like to improve
    if "key" not in temp_dict:
        raise CustomException("Message key is missing from dict")
    if "key1" not in temp_dict:
        raise CustomException("Message key1 is missing from dict")
    if "key2" not in temp_dict:
        raise CustomException("Message key2 is missing from dict")
    if "key3" not in temp_dict:
        raise CustomException("Message key3 is missing from dict")

my_dict = {}
my_dict["key"] = "test"
my_dict["key1"] = "test"
my_dict["key2"] = "test"

my_method(my_dict)
```

Link to Python Fiddle [Link](http://pythonfiddle.com/checking-dict-for-keys)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looping can help:

```
def my_method(temp_dict):
    for key in ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
        if key not in temp_dict:
            raise CustomException("Message {} is missing from dict".format(key))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about writing all the keys you want to check for in a tuple?

```
def mymethod(temp_dict):
    mykeys = ('key1', 'key2', 'key3', ..., 'keyN')
    for k in mykeys:
        if k not in temp_dict:
            raise CustomException("{} missing from dictionary".format(k))
```

In this way anytime you want to add a new key to check for you can just add it to the tuple instead of duplicating code.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use a schema library such as [voluptuous](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous), in which you define your dictionary schema, by defining which keys are required and which are optional and even which acceptable types the keys can have.

On the other hand I have this nifty little function that I've used so far if you would only need to validate if all required keys are present. First we define a list containing all the required keys. Then we check if the given dictionary has all these required keys present using the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) method.

```
def validate_params(params, req_keys=[]):                                           
    """                                                                      
    Verify if all required keys are present in the dictionary passed   
    to this method                                                           

    :param params: Parameter Dictionary to check
    :param req_keys: These Keys are required in the dictionary
    :rtype: Boolean                                                          
    :returns: True or False                                                  
    """                                                                      
    if all(_ in params for _ in req_keys):                       
        return True                                                          
    raise CustomException("Not all keys present in dictionary")
```

I've added a fiddle on [pythonfiddle.com](http://pythonfiddle.com/validate-if-all-keys-are-present).

Answer (score 1):

The most Pythonic way to do this is with a loop:

```
>>> class CustomException(Exception):
...     pass
...
>>> keys = 'key0 key1 key2 key3'.split()
>>> my_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, xrange(4))}
>>>
>>> for k in keys:
...     if not k in my_dict:
...         raise CustomException('Key %s not in dictionary.' % k)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
__main__.CustomException: Key key4 not in dictionary.
>>>
```

However, an even more Pythonic way to do this would be for your function to simply do a `try/except` for each required key in your function as you use it.  For example:

```
>>> keys = 'key0 key1 key2 key3 key4'.split()
>>>
>>> def f(my_dict):
...     for key in keys:
...         try:
...             print k, my_dict[k]
...         except KeyError:
...             raise CustomException('Key %s not in dictionary.' % k)
...
>>> my_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(keys[:-1], xrange(len(keys) - 1))}
>>> assert my_dict == {'key0': 0, 'key1': 1, 'key2': 2, 'key3': 3}  # Note no 'key4'
>>> f(my_dict)
key4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in f
__main__.CustomException: Key key4 not in dictionary.
>>>
```

This is known as the "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission" (or: "EAFP") principle.  Proceed with what you plan to do until something stops you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
if any(k not in temp_dict for k in ('key', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3')):
    raise CustomException("Some keys are missing from dict")
```